Y-distance from point to polygon
I try to calculate the Y-distance from a point inside a polygon to this polygon in positive and negative Y-directions.
So far I use shapely to create the polygon, but i am not bound to this.
There might be the case, that multiple edges are above the point (case 2 in my image). Then I would like to have the smallest distance.

One solution I thought about was to generate an array containing Y-Coordinates from 0 to lets say 100 in small steps and iteratively add up those coordinates to the Y-coordinate of my point and check for every iteration, if the point is still inside the polygon. However, I hope there is a more elegant way to do this.
I know, that shapely offers the possibility to calculate the minimum distance from a point to a polygon (poly.exterior.distance(point)), but I don´t see, how this can help me, as this is not in Y-direction.
Thank you for your help!

Please avoid adding image and/or external linked to code. Add your code/explanation here in Post.

You could construct a vertical line through your point and calculate the intersection with the polygon. Then calculate the distance from your point to the intersections.

IIUC, here is one way to compute the distances from the point to the closest edges (vertically) :
from shapely import LineString, MultiLineString

def dis_to(p, poly):
    lines = LineString(
        [
            (p.x, poly.bounds[1::2][0]),
            (p.x, poly.bounds[1::2][1]),
        ]
    ).intersection(poly)

    lines = (
        lines if type(lines) == MultiLineString else MultiLineString([lines])
    )
    out_line = next(_l for _l in lines.geoms if p.intersects(_l))
    
    return out_line, [
        round(p.distance(_p), 2)
        for _p in out_line.boundary.geoms
    ]

l1, dist1 = dis_to(p1, poly1)
l2, dist2 = dis_to(p2, poly2)
l3, dist2 = dis_to(p3, poly3)

Output :
>>> l1, dist1
# (<LINESTRING (4.5 1.417, 4.5 7)>, [2.58, 3.0])

>>> l2, dist2
# (<LINESTRING (5.5 1.3, 5.5 6.75)>, [3.7, 1.75])

>>> l3, dist3
# (<LINESTRING (6 4, 6 9.6)>, [2.0, 3.6])


Plot (see full code) :


I noticed, that the function works, if the point is below two edges (like it is in my case 2), but if it is above two edges, not the minimal distance but the longer one is returned. Do you have any idea why?

Got you ;) I made a small fix to change how we build the out_line. Can you check it out ?
